# Uploading images to App Engine in Java using Jquery blueimp

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-engine, blobstore, blueimp

Could someone point me to some resource to implement multiple image uploads to Java app engine blobstore using JQuery blueimp plugin?
The docs have a maven implementation but I understand porting an existing project to Maven is tricky and I want avoid this step.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I also kept struggling with this plugin but since the documentation is old so things were not working properly with the latest GAE version due to asm and some other jars.

I tried using this [Plugin](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php) and its working absolutely fine for me. Also in the backend I have used the normal code for file upload as provided in GAE blobstore documentation. You can also check the real implementation of this plugin on this [URL](https://testslider1.appspot.com/).

Comment: The upload with this plugin doesnt seem to work the trivial way for i get an error saying must be called from a blob upload call back request. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you follow the example here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Complete_sample_application there is a URL which is generated before every upload request on which the data needs to be posted. You need to pass this URL to plugin to make it work.