# Upload image to google bucket using jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: google-app-engine, jquery-file-upload

I've been able to get jQuery-File-Upload from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload (python version) to allow my website users to upload images to a google app engine app, however it saves the images (for a limited time) as a blob.

It would be preferable to have the images saved in a google bucket but I'm unable to figure out how to get the files to save in a bucket rather than a blob.

Can anyone recommend a similar way for my website visitors to upload images to my google bucket, or if jQuery-File-Upload to do so?

Comment: Refer to my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828787/uploading-images-to-app-engine-in-java-using-jquery-blueimp/19834787#19834787

Comment: Also you can refer my other post in these question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421460/upload-a-file-using-spring-multipartfile-and-google-app-engine/23425398#23425398       &    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306790/how-can-i-upload-an-thumbnail-image-blob-at-the-same-time-as-an-entity-into-a/15309278#15309278

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a cloud API to directly upload files to google cloud bucket via javascript, however implementing security could make things a bit sticky.

In general,It should be fairly easy to use google cloud services found [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/storage/v1/)

[use storage insert api call](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/storage/v1/storage.objects.insert)

Now if you like to give access to clients to upload data on you application's behalf, then you may have to build a signed url ,signed with your key and then directly upload to cloud, read more [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

I find it easy to do server side operations if the upload size is fairly small by using BlobStore API. You can use the Blobstore API to store blobs in Cloud Storage instead of storing them in Blobstore. Read all about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage). 
This method might be the easiest to implement in your case .

Answer (score 1):

I created an Appengine Python signed url example [here](https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-upload):[image: GCS signed url upload]